# Wiring a UK plug without coloured wires - help!

Tags: wiring

I am trying to put a UK plug on an old record player and the wires (please see picture) are not colour coded! How do i wire it up?!

[image]

Comment: Does one of the wires have ribs or a white stripe?

Comment: No sadly not! They are both identical

Answer (score 1):

If this is an older record player, it probably does not need a polarized plug (where the neutral is denoted). Polarity would come into play with a newer record player.

Assuming you use Type G plugs, you could buy [this replacement end](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Status-13-3-Pin-Plug-White/dp/B00J9B0YMU) and wire up the two plugs, omitting the ground prong.

Comment: So i can attach either wire to earth and live?

Comment: No. Attach one to the hot and one to the neutral. Do not attach anything to ground/earth

Comment: Many thanks - very much appreciate your help.

Comment: If my answer was helpful you can click the green check